# I an unable to start npm getting error

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, npm

I am working on nodejs project and unable to start nodejs.

In my existing angular project and after creating a fresh project with

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

---

after that

```
ng new mean-angular5
```

---

then

```
ng serve
```

---

then

```
npm install --save express body-parser morgan body-parser serve-favicon
```

---

I try to run npm start `npm start` showing error..

```
npm start
```

---

does not working

[image: error log]

Comment: Its showing some error in your cmd...May be some braces or comma is missing

Comment: Please post your textual error as text.

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force` then install `npm install`.

Comment: okay @Sagar Gavhane thanks for suggestion i use npm cache clean --force then npm install then i start npm start getting same error..

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm start`

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: okay thanks for suggestion  i deleted the node_modules folder then use npm cache clean --force
npm install then i start npm start getting same error..